# How to solve TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fName')

Tags: javascript

this my code :

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html")
});

app.post("/", function(res, req){
    const fName =  req.body.fName;
    const lName = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;

    const data = {
        members : [
            {
                email_address: email,
                status: "subscribed",
                merge_feilds:{
                    FNAME: firstName,
                    LNAME: lastName
             }
        }
    ]
    };

    const Jsondata = JSONstringify(data);

    const url = "https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/eca64732d1";

    const options= {
        method: "POST",
        auth:"string1:60ca81db08a41da8672a40261c9d7afd-us21"
    };

    const request = https.request(url, options, function(response){
    response.on("data", function(data){
        console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    })
})
    request.write(Jsondata);
    request.end();
});




app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("server is running on port 3000");
});
```

when i run it it shows an error, but i dont know what is wrong, and how to fix it.

Comment: Can you share the full error text you are seeing?

Comment: What is the `Content-Type` header of your request? urlencoded middleware only parses urlencoded request data.

Answer (score -1):

The issue is in the post call you have defined. The parameters are in the wrong sequence. If you read express docs order is `(req,res)` but you have used res as the first which is why it is not able to extract `fName`.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
    const fName =  req.body.fName;
    const lName = req.body.lName;
    const email = req.body.email;
```

Comment: i tried it it still does not work

Comment: ReferenceError: firstName is not defined
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\app.js:27:28
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15

Comment: at Function.process_params (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:137:5
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)

Comment: The last 2 comments are the error

Comment: itried tit it worked but ow there is an other rerror

Comment: ReferenceError: JSONstringify is not defined
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\app.js:34:22
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15

Comment: at Function.process_params (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at D:\NEWSLETTER APP\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:137:5
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:203:9)